# Use GitVersion to see which commit a version points to

Tags: git, gitversion

Is it possible to use [GitVersion](https://github.com/ParticularLabs/GitVersion) to see exactly what commit a particular version points to e.g. 1.7.0-unstable144 is version X?

So reversing it's normal job of labelling a particular commit and instead getting the commit from a version.

Notably this version does not have a matching tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In it's current implementation, no, that is not possible.

You might want to suggest this as a [feature](https://github.com/ParticularLabs/GitVersion/issues) though, as I can see some merit in doing something like that.

Whether it is possible, would need some discussion :-)